# Why my Makefile works fine after deleting `%.o: %.c`?

Tags: c, makefile

I accidentally deleted the `%.o: %.c` section in my Makefile, but it still works fine; could somebody let me know WHY?

Here's my Makefile:

```
CC = gcc    
CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -O3
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))

myProgram: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ -O3 $^
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f myProgram *.o *.c~ *.h~ *.swp
```

and here's the output of clean make:

```
$ make clean; make
rm -f myProgram *.o *.c~ *.h~ *.swp
gcc  -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -O3   -c -o anotherFile.o anotherFile.c
gcc  -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -O3   -c -o oneFile.o oneFile.c
gcc  -o myProgram -O3 anotherFile.o oneFile.o
```

Comment: make has some [builtin rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html).

Comment: @churill do you mean **Compiling C programs
n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form ‘$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’.**, it'll auto-compile anyway?

Comment: Yes.  For programs built from a single source file, you don't even need a makefile.  Running `make -f /dev/null single-file` will compile `single-fike.c` into the program `single-file`.

Comment: Run your make with `-r` to disable built-in rules and spot errors early.

Comment: got it, thanks you all